# Current path location of page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use angularJS to make a web page using `ngView` for 1 page and multiview.

How do I show page location of current page, as in `Home/abc/dcv` .
As in this web page https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location, it should be  / Developer Guide / Using `$location` .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try $location.absUrl();